# Separate Data Based on Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Lets say I have the following data set

```
 [[0 1994]
  [0 1965]
  [0, 1943]
  [1, 1994]
  [1,1965]  
  [2, 1948]]
```

I want to achieve the following output by separating out the data into individual arrays based on the value in the first row using numpy or Pandas methods instead of loops.

```
 [
  [[0 1994]
   [0 1965]
   [0 1943]]

   [[1 1994]
    [1 1965]] 

   [[2, 1948]]
              ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the expected indices based on the differences of the firs columns' items and then split the array based on those indices:

```
In [22]: inds = np.where(np.diff(a[:,0]) != 0)[0] + 1

In [23]: np.split(a, inds)
Out[23]: 
[array([[   0, 1994],
        [   0, 1965],
        [   0, 1943]]), array([[   1, 1994],
        [   1, 1965]]), array([[   2, 1948]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

The pandas way to do is to pass the data to `DataFrame` and then `groupby` operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x.values).values
```

Output:

```
[array([[   0, 1994],
        [   0, 1965],
        [   0, 1943]]), array([[   1, 1994],
        [   1, 1965]]), array([[   2, 1948]])]
```